# Trigger error if no global instance of a class exists

Tags: c++

For an application I need to ensure that one type (`Instance`) has been registered with another (`System`) before being used in conjunction with it.

Registering occurs by creating a global instance of the `Register` class:

```
// Instance.cpp
#include "Instance.h"
#include "System.h"
#include "Register.h"

static Register<Instance, System> instanceRegistration;
```

Once registered, `Instance` can be used in conjunction with `System`, in this simplified example by calling the `runme` function:

```
// main.cpp
#include "Instance.h"
#include "System.h"

template <typename T, typename T_System>
void runme() {
    // TODO: error if type T was not registered for type T_System.
    // ...
    // Code that fails if no instance of Register<Instance, System> exists
    // ...
}

int main() {
    runme<Instance, System>();
}
```

Calling `runme` with a combination of template arguments that have not been registered together should fail (the real code would segfault in this case).

Currently, a run-time check is made in `runme` against a global `bool` that is set in `Register`'s constructor. If the global `bool` is `false`, an exception is thrown. This works fine.

However, I would like to move the error check to compile time, since in theory the linker should be able to determine if a global instance of the `Register` class exists.

### Question:

Is there some way to generate a linker error if a call is made to `runme<Instance, System>()` without there existing a global variable of type `Register<Instance, System>`?

---

The additional header files are as follows:

```
// Instance.h
class Instance { };
```

---

```
// System.h
class System { };
```

---

```
// Register.h
template <typename T, typename T_System>
class Register {
public:
    Register() {
        // Some side effects...
    }
};
```

Comment: And you do not just want to auto create such global instances?

Comment: @Yakk No, since only certain combinations of types should have such an instance. There are a large amount of `T`s, and quite a few `T_System`s, and in general each `T` is associated with a single `T_System`.

Comment: Is there a reason it must be in linking stage?  You couldn't make the link explicit in a header file, adjacent to a given `T` say?

Comment: @Yakk I'm not quite sure what you mean. The association between `T` and one or more `T_System`s itself is explicit, either in `T`'s or some other source file. Error checking currently occurs at run time, but I would like to move it to compile time (triggering a linker error).

Comment: Why do you want link time, snd bot compile tine errors?  Would rewuiring header file "declaration of compatibility" be no good?  What if the cpp file libe was not needed?

Comment: @Yakk Got it. Unfortunately that doesn't work, because registration may occur in a different compilation unit, and can't be moved to `T`'s header file.

Comment: ... and why do you want that?  If you make it visible, the connection, you can make the registration happen automatically when the connection is made, and you get compile time errors, instead of link time.  If your editor does syntax error highlighting, it can even tell you the act is illegal as you type it.

Comment: @Yakk Because some translation units know only about `T`, and not about `T_System`. It is allowed to define a new `T_System`, and register an existing `T` with that `T_System`. This must be possible without modifying `T`'s source code.

Comment: but people can only call `runme` if they know about a `T_System`.  So you could put the header-file registration (either via ADL-based registration function or via traits class or a mixture of both) where `T_System` is defined instead of where `T` is defined.  So long as nobody can see **both** of `T` and `T_System` without seeing the registration, all is peachy.

Comment: @Yakk The problem is finding a place that is guaranteed to be seen by everything that uses **both** `T` and `T_System`, but is not also seen by anything seeing only either `T` or `T_System`. If the link is placed in `T`'s header file, that header file must include `T_System`'s header, which would make `T_System` visible to everything that uses `T`. Conversely, if the link is placed in `T_System`'s header, that header must include `T`'s header. It would therefore not be possible to have anything use just `T` without also knowing about `T_System` (or vice versa depending on where the link is).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't perfect, but it can get you most of the way there. First, declare a unimplemented function called (say) `EnsureRegistered()` that is templated on the same arguments as `Register`; maybe in Register.h:

```
template<typename T, typename T_System>
void EnsureRegistered(); // not implemented here!
```

Now, whenever you create a `Register`, provide an explicit specialization of `EnsureRegistered()` (maybe use a preprocessor macro to automate this):

```
Register<int, int> g_Register_i_i;

template<>
void EnsureRegistered<int, int>() {}
```

Finally, call the function in `runme()` (or just take its address and assign it to something if performance is that critical):

```
template<typename T, typename T_System>
void runme()
{
    EnsureRegistered<T, T_System>();
    // ...
}
```

Now, `runme<int, int>()` will build, but `runme<int, double>()` will give a link error.

Comment: I've been trying to come up with a way to cleanly combine the Register instantiation and function implementation, but no luck so far. Any suggestions? I prefer to avoid the use of a macro, but there may be no other alternative...

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't been able to think of one that doesn't lean on the preprocessor.